# how to make radio button independent of others in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am making a checklist, I have the categories and each category has its intervention, you have to check according to what corresponds to the problem that is that for example.

**CheckList.vue**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: top">Categoria</th>
              <th colspan="2">Existe</th>
              <th colspan="3">Estado</th>
              <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: top">
                Observación
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Si</th>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Bueno</th>
              <th>Regular</th>
              <th>Malo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody
            v-for="(formatchecklist, index) in formatchecklists"
            :key="index"
          >
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" class="table-secondary">
                <em>{{ index + 1 }}.- {{ formatchecklist.categoria }}</em>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr
              v-for="intervencion in formatchecklist.intervenciones"
              :key="intervencion.id"
            >
              <td>{{ intervencion.intervencion }}</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="existe"
                  value="si"
                  v-model="checkExiste"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="existe"
                  value="no"
                  v-model="checkExiste"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="estado"
                  value="bueno"
                  v-model="checkEstado"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="estado"
                  value="regular"
                  v-model="checkEstado"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="estado"
                  value="malo"
                  v-model="checkEstado"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <textarea
                  name="observacion"
                  class="form-control"
                ></textarea>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a
                  class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                  @click.prevent=""
                  title="Editar"
                >
                  <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

When selecting the first radio there is no problem, the problem is when selecting the second radio of the second row, intervention 2, the first one is deselected.

https://codepen.io/lucascardemil/pen/GRMejWK

and how can i get that data

Comment: You need to change the radio name to be different like  `:name="'existe' + intervencion.id`.Do you use vue2 or vue3?

Answer (score 1):

The radios' names are the same so each rows' radio whose name is `existe` will action like radio group,so only one is selected.

In other words, you need to assign different names for each rows' radio button group.And the model-binding you also need to be changed to save it correctly corresponding to each intervencion if necessary.

Below is my sample code in vuejs 2 which you could refer to.

```
<template>
<div>
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: top">Categoria</th>
              <th colspan="2">Existe</th>
              <th colspan="3">Estado</th>
              <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: top">
                Observación
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Si</th>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Bueno</th>
              <th>Regular</th>
              <th>Malo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody
            v-for="(formatchecklist, index) in formatchecklists"
            :key="index"
          >
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" class="table-secondary">
                <em>{{ index + 1 }}.- {{ formatchecklist.categoria }}</em>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr
              v-for="intervencion in formatchecklist.intervenciones"
              :key="intervencion.id"
            >
              <td>{{ intervencion.intervencion }}</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  :name="'existe' + intervencion.id"
                  value="si"
                  v-model="intervencion.existeValue"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                 :name="'existe' + intervencion.id"
                  value="no"
                  v-model="intervencion.existeValue"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  :name="'estado' + intervencion.id"
                  value="bueno"
                  v-model="intervencion.estadoValue"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  :name="'estado' + intervencion.id"
                  value="regular"
                  v-model="intervencion.estadoValue"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  :name="'estado' + intervencion.id"
                  value="malo"
                  v-model="intervencion.estadoValue"
                />
                <label></label>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <textarea
                :name="'observacion' + intervencion.id"
                 v-model="intervencion.observacion"
                  class="form-control"
                ></textarea>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a
                  class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                  @click.prevent=""
                  title="Editar"
                >
                  <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
 </table>
 <pre>
     {{JSON.stringify(formatchecklists, null, 2)}}
 </pre>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default  {
  data() {
    return {
        formatchecklists :[{
          "categoria":"category1",
          "intervenciones":[{
              "id":1,
              "intervencion":"intervencion1",
              "existeValue":"",
              "estadoValue":"",
              "observacion":""
          },
          {
              "id":2,
              "intervencion":"intervencion2",
              "existeValue":"",
              "estadoValue":"",
              "observacion":""
          }]
      },
      {
          "categoria":"category2",
          "intervenciones":[{
              "id":3,
              "intervencion":"intervencion3",
              "existeValue":"",
              "estadoValue":"",
              "observacion":""
          },
          {
              "id":4,
              "intervencion":"intervencion4",
              "existeValue":"",
              "estadoValue":"",
              "observacion":""
          }]
      }]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: How can I do it with the textarea without repeating the same thing in all of them, that is, in each box you can write to a different ?

Comment: @LucasCardemilVillegas It is similar to radio.Modify their name and v-model.I update my demo above.